# What does a pointer to this object create?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Here DynamicArray is a dynamic array template class. It's constructor takes 1 int argument. What does this pointer actually do, though? It creates a pointer q that points to an address, but does the constructor actually instantiate some unnamed garbage object?

```
   DynamicArray<int>       x(12);
    DynamicArray<double>   *q;
```

What does this pointer q create?

Comment: It creates nothing. It's just an uninitialized pointer to an instance of `DynamicArray<double>`.

Comment: Some pointers point at another object.  This one doesn't (yet).

Comment: Pointers don't create anything. Your *declaration* creates a *pointer.* Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pointer creates nothing. It is a definition of a pointer that can be used to point to objects of type `DynamicArray<double>` For example

```
DynamicArray<double>       x(12);
DynamicArray<double>   *q;

q = &x;
```

Take into account that in your original code snippet `DynamicArray<int>` and `DynamicArray<double>` are two different types. You may not write for example

```
DynamicArray<int>       x(12);
DynamicArray<double>   *q;

q = &x;
```